# Hang up the system when working with dotnetbar

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017, freeze, dotnetbar

I'm having trouble working with devcomponent dotnetbar.
My problem is that when I apply to move panels or groups on the form, the movement is extremely slow and the Visual Studio program locks and hangs for awhile,
Or do I have a problem with renaming one of the form elements to slow down and slow down Visual Studio software?
My Windows Laptop: Windows 10
Laptop Specifications:
CPU: Cori7
Ram: 8g
Hard disk Sd

Comment: may guess is there is a problem with your usage, without giving context and how your using it, people are going to find it very hard/impossible to help you.

Comment: if you are having an issue with the components they do have a support page -https://www.devcomponents.com/support.aspx